# Understanding ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(double ratio)

Tags: java, excel, file, apache-poi

I am using this function call, because when I read a trusted file, It results in zipbomb error.

**ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(double ratio)**

```
   FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("/file/path/report.xlsx"); 
   ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(-1.0d);
   XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
```

I am trying to understand how it works?

The only source I could find is https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/util/ZipSecureFile.html

But, couldn't get a clear picture as I am new to this concept.

What are the differences between

```
ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(-1.0d);
```

vs

```
ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(0.009);
```

vs

```
ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(0);
```

Comment: When the documentation doesn't tell you everything you need to know and it's an open source project, read the source code! https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/util/ZipSecureFile.java?view=markup#l262 The implementation in POI 3.17 will treat 0.009, 0.0, and -1.0 the same so long as the compression ratio is no better than 1%. Most XML files are about 90% compressible, resulting in a zip file that is 10% of the expanded size. So the default compression ratio allows files to be 1 order of magnitude more compressible than a typical XML file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A zip bomb detection works the following way:

While uncompressing it checks the ratio `compressedBytes/uncompressedBytes` and if this falls below a special amount (`MinInflateRatio`), then a bomb was detected.

So if the ratio `compressedBytes/uncompressedBytes` is `0.01d` for example, then that means that the compressed file is 100 times smaller than the uncompressed one whithout information lost. In other words, the compressed file stores the same information in only 1% of the file size, the uncompressed one needs. This is really unlikely using real life data.

To show how unlikely it is we could take a look (in a popular scientific manner) on how compression works:

Let's have the string

`"This is a test for compressing having long count of characters which always occurs the same sequence."`

This needs 101 bytes. Let's say this string occurs 100,000 times in the file. Then uncompressed it would need 10,100,000 bytes. A compression algorithm would give that string a ID and would storing the string only once mapping it to that ID and would storing 100,000 times the ID where the string occurs in the file. That would need 101 bytes + 1 byte (ID) + 100,000 bytes (IDs) = 100,102 bytes. And this would have a ratio `compressedBytes/uncompressedBytes` of `0.009911089d` for example.

So if we set the `MinInflateRatio` to lower than `0.01d`, then we accept such unlikely data compression rates.

Also we can see, that the ratio `compressedBytes/uncompressedBytes` can only be `0` if `compressedBytes` is 0. But this would mean that there are no bytes to uncompress. So a `MinInflateRatio` of `0.0d` can never be reached nor be undershot. So with a `MinInflateRatio` of `0.0d` all possible ratios will be accepted.

Of course a `MinInflateRatio` of `-1.0d` also can never be reached nor be undershot. So using this also all possible ratios will be accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It makes more sense now. Thanks :)

Comment: @Chid: Most times the ZIP bomb detection is only a problem when test data are used. The exactly same "lorem ipsum..." paragraph used thousands of times in the file would lead to such unlikely data compression rates for example.

Comment: @AxelRichter or there is a vector graphic file (EMF) and it has redundant parts - just as in my case. :)